# How can I emulate (inject) system-wide keystrokes and mouse movement via a TCP server?

Tags: keyboard, remote, tcp, input, remote-control

I'm running Debian on a dedicated HTPC without a keyboard or mouse attached.

Most users will use LIRC and an IR receiver to control the system, but my remote control is advanced and can send direct TCP/UDP commands to my network.

Is there a way to emulate a keyboard (and mouse) on the system and accept commands from a TCP/UDP server?  For example, if TCP port 8888 receives an 'a' then I want the keystroke 'a' sent to ANY actively running process on the console.

I've searched for solutions and it looks like xdotool is available for X11 injection or I could write a uinput driver?

I was hoping that LIRC (or something else) could just be installed and run as a TCP server injecting commands to uninput but I'm not sure that's possible or will do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

[`evemu`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Evemu/) should be able to do this. You'd set up a virtual event source using `evemu-device` (with an appropriate descriptor, which you can copy from a real event device), and then inject events using `evemu-event`. This can synthesise any input event, including keystrokes and mouse movement.